# ImageSpan is cut off / incorrectly aligned

Tags: android

I am implementing emoticons using the following code:

```
            builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(mContext, resId, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE),
                        start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE );
```

The result (builder) is set as text to a TextView. It works just fine if the span is surrounded by text, i.e. when the start > 0 and the end < length - 1, but the image is cut off (shifted up) if there is no text around it. how do I fix that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For the record, after trying to solve this for many hours, unfortunately I believe this is an Android bug and I don't see a "real" solution. I ended up adding a space after my smiley like the answer from @plowman.  I want to mention that the Hangouts app from Google has the same issue! Add a single smiley in the message input, then add a space: the smiley moves by a few pixels...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as there are no suggestions, I am going to use the following solution in the meantime: if there is no text - use ALIGN_BOTTOM flag, otherwise use ALIGN_BASELINE...

Comment: Still no better answers?

Answer (score 7):

Following on to your solution, here is my custom `DynamicDrawableSpan` I use in place of `ImageSpan`. The `draw()` method (copied from DynamicDrawableSpan and modified) ensures that there is text before aligning with the baseline.

```
class StickerSpan extends DynamicDrawableSpan {
    Drawable mDrawable;

    public StickerSpan(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
        super(DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
        setBitmap(context, bitmap);
    }

    public void setBitmap(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
        mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
        int width = mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int height = mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, width > 0 ? width : 0, height > 0 ? height : 0); 
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable() {
        return mDrawable;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, CharSequence text,
                     int start, int end, float x, 
                     int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint) {
        Drawable b = mDrawable;
        canvas.save();

        int transY = bottom - b.getBounds().bottom;
        if (mVerticalAlignment == ALIGN_BASELINE) {
            int textLength = text.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < textLength; i++) {
                if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(text.charAt(i))) {
                    transY -= paint.getFontMetricsInt().descent;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        canvas.translate(x, transY);
        b.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I also ran into this issue and could not find a proper solution. The workaround I used looks like this:

```
if(message.length() == 1){
//This is a hack to get past an android bug that misaligns ImageSpan's when they are all alone.
    message += " ";
}
builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try set the bound of the drawable. For example:

```
        BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
        int width = bmd.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int height = bmd.getIntrinsicHeight();
        bmd.setBounds(
                0,
                0,
                (int)width,
                (int)height);

        ImageSpan img = new ImageSpan(bmd);
        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(
          someString);
        spannableString.setSpan(
          img, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: This didn't change anything for me. In fact, looking at the source of ImageSpan, it looks like the call to seBounds is already done when using a resource id, hence it seems normal that this doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me I just hadn't set the bounds of the drawable before I passed it to the ImageSpan.

You can set the "intrinsic bounds" of the drawable by doing something like:

```
Drawable drawable = // what you use to create/get your drawable
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(drawable);
```

Comment: This is not only incorrect (it should be 0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()) but even after fixing, this doesn't solve the issue, at least for me.

Comment: Ah your right about the order of the params. Fixed the typo. This did resolve text being cutoff in my case. My guess is there are a few cases where text may be cutoff. Some answers here may not work for every case, but it is possible that it may help someone so I maintain it as an possible answer.